# Statically linking GLEW from source with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, glew

I am somewhat new to cmake and completely new to glew, glfw, and the like. I'm following a [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWU8EltWTfM&list=PLlrATfBNZ98fqE45g3jZA_hLGUrD4bo6_) to learn more about game engines and programming.

My problem is linking the static glew library in my project using cmake.

First, I start with the glew source code from http://mcs.une.edu.au/doc/glew-devel/index.html.

I compile it by:

```
cd build; cmake ./cmake; make glew_s
```

This adds a lib directory into the build directory with libGLEW.a

A shortened version of my CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)
project (TestProject CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

###########################
# GLEW
###########################
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glew)
```

and in `Dependencies/GLEW` I have another `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Add glew source and header files  
file(GLOB_RECURSE glew-lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/*)  
file(GLOB_RECURSE glew-headers ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/GL/*)

add_library(glew ${glew-lib} ${glew-headers})  
target_include_directories(glew PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/GL")
```

---

I put a copy of the `libGLEW.a` file into the lib directory and the include directory is copied from the glew source code include directory. It holds the GL directory, which contains the header files `glew.h`, `wglew.h`, `eglew.h`, and `glxew.h`.

When I run `cmake` I get the error:

```
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "glew".  
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: glew
```

---

The glew source code also has a src directory with `glew.c` in it, but if I put it in the `libs` directory and include it in the `Dependencies/GLEW/CMakeLists.txt` like:

```
# Add glew source and header files  
file(GLOB_RECURSE glew-lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/*.c)
file(GLOB_RECURSE glew-headers ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/GL/*)
add_library(glew ${glew-lib} ${glew-headers})
target_include_directories(glew PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```

I get the error:

```
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may
be not be built correctly.  
Missing variable is: CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT  
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may
be not be built correctly.  
Missing variable is: CMAKE_C_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY
```

---

Lastly, I have tried just including the `glew.c` and headers in the root `CMakeLists.txt` like:

```
#########################
# GLEW  
#########################
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW/lib/")
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW/include/GL/")
```

Here `cmake` will finish, but it won't be able to compile, saying classes do not name a type and/or are not declared in this scope.

Any help would be appreciated. I was under the impression that the `libGLEW.a` was the static library, and all I would have to do is link and compile it along with the headers, but that did not work.

Comment: If the file is called `libGLEW.a` you should tell CMake to link `GLEW` not `glew`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: In the first code snipped `glew` is a **target name**, which is created by the second code snippet. In CMake targets names could be any.

Comment: @mjp5595: Do you **already** have file `libGLEW.a` or not? If yes, no needs to build GLEW once more. If no, use the build process provided by the GLEW project (`make`, `make install`), not needs to (re)implement it in CMake. After obtaining `libGLEW.a` all you need is to adjust include directories for **your** project (with `include_directories`) and link with an existing library, as it is described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you. I did not use "make install", which was most of my problem!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I forgot to use

```
make install
```

after using make the first time, so I was using the incorrect libGLEW.a file.

After including the proper libGLEW.a file, my directory structure had

> ./Dependencies/GLEW/include/GL/*.h           //header files
>   ./Dependencies/GLEW/lib/libGLEW.a            //source file

Finally, the TopLevel CMakeLists.txt is changed to include:

```
add_library(glew STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)

set_target_properties(glew PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW/lib/libGLEW.a )
set_target_properties(glew PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW/include )
```

If I want to include the library from a lower CMakeLists.txt such as /Dependencies/GLEW/CMakeLists.txt  Then I would have to first export the library from there and then import it at the topLevel CMakeLists.txt file.

Now, in order to use glew headers in my project I can just use #include .